# Copying a string into a dynamical two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, dynamic

like the title already states I would like to copy various strings into a two-dimensional array. Each string has a different size therefore I need to use memory reallocation. The code below should do this job, but somehow I cannot get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

char **str = NULL;
int str_num = 1;

// get string
char *str_new = "hey mate\0";

printf("%s\n",str_new);

// reallocation for str_new
str = realloc(str,str_num*sizeof(char));
str[str_num-1] = realloc(str,strlen(str_new));

// copy string to new space
strcpy(*str, str_new);

// displaying string
printf("%s\n",str[str_num-1]);


return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: Two things: The compiler automatically adds the string terminator `'\0'` to all string literals, and all string literals are read-only so a pointer to them should be `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is in the reallocation:

```
str = realloc(str,str_num*sizeof(char));
```

You only allocate space for *a single byte* and not for a pointer to `char`. This leds to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change to e.g.

```
str = realloc(str,str_num*sizeof(char*));
```

Another problem, and also a cause for undefined behavior is the actual string allocation:

```
str[str_num-1] = realloc(str,strlen(str_new));
```

Here you are reallocating *`str`* and not `str[0]`. *And* you don't alocate space for the string terminator.

For this don't use `realloc` at all, since you're only allocating this once you only need either `malloc`, or just use the `strdup` function to do both allocation and copying in one call:

```
str[str_num - 1] = strdup(str_new);
```

---

By the way, when using `realloc` never assign to the same pointer you're passing in as first argument, because if the `realloc` function fails it will return `NULL` and you will loose the original pointer. Instead assign to a temporary pointer, and if it's non-null then assign to the actual pointer.

Comment: is it okay to use realloc() on a string before it has been allocated using malloc or calloc?

Comment: @ryyker its ok to use `realloc` on a NULL pointer. (acts like `malloc`).

Comment: @ryyker Passing a `NULL` pointer to `realloc` is equivalent to do `malloc`.

Comment: `str = realloc(str, newsize)` could cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Beside correcting (as pointed in [Joachim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27691706/2455888))

```
str = realloc(str,str_num*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
str = realloc(str,str_num*sizeof(*str));
```

you should note that, the pointer passed to `realloc` must be the pointer returned by any `malloc` family function or it points to `NULL`. You can do it as

```
str[str_num-1] = NULL;
str[str_num-1] = realloc(str[str_num-1], strlen(str_new)+1);
```

Comment: @WhozCraig, you probably missed out the `*` in your suggested correction. Both statements are identical.

Comment: @B.Shankar `strlen(str_new)` and `strlen(str_new)+1` are anything-but identical. I think you mean hacks original post, which yes, is missing the `*`. Added.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **str = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n); /* n= number of pointers */
```

Allocate memory for the pointer's first then allocate memory to individual pointer like

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
       /* copy your string to the allocated memory location here*/
   }
```

Else you can have

```
char **str = NULL;

str = realloc(str,str_num * sizeof(char *));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't understand what realloc does, the code you posted is not right, that code should be written this way

```
char **str = NULL;
int str_num = 1;

// get string
char *str_new = "hey mate\0";

printf("%s\n",str_new);

/*
    // reallocation for str_new
    str = realloc(str, str_num * sizeof(char));
 */ 
/* allocate space for `str_num` pointers of char */
str = malloc(str_num * sizeof(char *));
if (str == NULL) /* check it worked */
    return -1;

/* allocate space for the number of characters in str_new and
 * the termination null byte 
 */
str[str_num - 1] = malloc(1 + strlen(str_new));
if (str[str_num - 1] == NULL)
{
    free(str);
    return -1;
}
/*
 * // copy string to new space
 * strcpy(*str, str_new);
 */
/* use the same index since if str_num > 1 the above is wrong */
strcpy(str[str_num - 1], str_new);

// displaying string
printf("%s\n",str[str_num - 1]);
```

realloc should be used like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char **str = NULL;
    int str_num;
    // get string
    char *str_new[2] = {"hey mate 1", "hey mate 2"};

    for (str_num = 0 ; str_num < 2 ; ++str_num)
    {
        char **pointer;
        printf("%s\n", str_new[str_num]);
        /*
            // reallocation for str_new
            str = realloc(str, str_num * sizeof(char));
         */ 

        /* re-allocate space for `str_num` pointers of char */
        pointer = realloc(str, (1 + str_num) * sizeof(char *));
        /* 
         * If you use
         * 
         *      str = realloc(str, str_num * sizeof(char *));
         * 
         * you wont be able to free(str) on failure
         */
        if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            int j;
            /* on failure cleanup and return */
            for (j = str_num - 1 ; j >= 0 ; --j)
                free(str[j]);
            free(str);

            return -1;
        }
        str = pointer;      

        /* allocate space for the number of characters in str_new and
         * the termination null byte 
         */
        str[str_num] = malloc(1 + strlen(str_new[str_num]));
        if (str[str_num] == NULL)
        {
            free(str);
            return -1;
        }
        /*
         * // copy string to new space
         * strcpy(*str, str_new);
         */
        /* use the same index since if str_num > 1 the above is wrong */
        strcpy(str[str_num], str_new[str_num]);

        // displaying string
        printf("%s\n",str[str_num]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

you should remember to `free` all the allocated memory.

Also you don't need to embed the `'\0'` in a string literal.